# How to use Apache Ivy with FREE and BASE plan?

Tags: ivy, cloudbees

As far as I understand the Jenkins Ivy plugin is not installed with the FREE and BASE plans of Cloudbees. What is the best approach to use Ivy without these plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway ivy not being a build tool but a dependency manager, your project needs to be configured to run another builder, probably ant or ?

Comment: Yes, I am using ant as build tool. If you have the Jenkins Ivy plugin installed you can use ivy in your build without extra effort. Currently I have got it working by placing the ivy.jar in the private webadv directory and added an ivy taskdef with classpath="/private/account-id/ivy-2.3.0.jar".

Answer (score 0):

I've added several Ivy related plugins to the Pro and Enterprise tiers.

Answer (score 0):

One possible work-around is add a bootstrap target that downloads and installs the ivy jar.

For example:

```
<target name="bootstrap">
   <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
   <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
</target>
```